# dockerized nginx proxy not forwarding request to a dockerized container

Tags: docker, nginx

I am trying to gather some information on what could be the possible avenues to look for when nginx-reverseproxy is not forwarding request to a docker container (let's called it app-core).

1. I am able to access app-core by doing a curl request from nginx-reverseproxy container.
2. Both nginx-proxy and app-core are running. Both are on the same network.
3. I don't think there is anything of interest in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf. Nevertheless, I have posted a snippet of it here

> ```
> upstream \ app-core.com {
>     # app-core for docker compose
>     server app-core:80;
> }
>
> server {
>   server_name \ app-core.com;
>   listen 80 ;
>   access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
>   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
> }
>
> server {
>   server_name \ app-core.com;
>   proxy_connect_timeout 5m;
>   proxy_send_timeout 5m;
>   proxy_read_timeout 5m;
>   send_timeout 5m;
>   listen 443 ssl ;
>   access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
>   ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
>   ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA;
>   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
>   ssl_session_timeout 5m;
>   ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
>   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/app-core.com.crt;
>   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/app-core.com.key;
>   add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
>   location / {
>       proxy_pass http://\ app-core.com;
>   }
> }
> ```

May I know what could be the possible issue here?

Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the docker commands or docker-compose file you use to run the services and the curl command you are trying?

Comment: voting to close as it turned out to be a minor mistake from my side. My entry in VIRTUAL _HOST was wrong hence the server name became '\ app-core.com' instead of 'app-core.com'.